# Netbeans won't start, and eclipse won't install

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, ide

Netbeans was running fine just last week (and has been since I installed it about two years ago). Now all the sudden it won't start (without showing any errors). I didn't change anything related to java on my computer, all I did in the past two weeks is to install some software that I needed.
Now, when I clique on its icon or start it from command prompt nothing happens. I followed some posts and used -trace to get the output log. But I don't know how to use it to find the problem. [The Netbeans log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BTIDgDR7hxR5q3CAsUbJf5MH-j1h4sAf/view?usp=sharing)

What I tried:

- I uninstalled Netbeans and Jdk and reinstalled them, I get the same problem.
- Running Netbeans from cmd with -vm option. Didn't work.
- Install Eclipse, but it won't even install and all I get is the log file that shows some error, I tried to look for them but failed to get anywhere. [The Eclipse log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mvJTqJ99N-VJCcKXzO9U7q6Ablw-1T4U/view?usp=sharing)
- Java_Home and path are all specified in the environment variables, and java programs compile and run just fine from Cmd. (all other environment variables and other system information are in the Eclipse log).

Please help, this is so frustrating, and I am even considering dual booting now that both IDEs aren't working. I also thought about trying other IDEs but figured that I might get the same problem. Thank you in advance.

I am running: windows8.1 , Netbeans8.2 , jdk1.8.0_191 and Eclipse oomph

**Update:**
The `path`environment variable is actually different than what eclipse log file shows, it is as follows:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\
WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\
Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin;C:\Program Files\metro\bin;C:\Program Files\
apache-ant-1.10.5\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin;C:\Program Files\g
lassfish5\glassfish\bin;C:\Program Files\glassfish5\bin`

Answer (score 0):

The other software you installed might have also installed its own Java version
that's incompatible.

Check your Java versions in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java` and your
environment variables (and especially PATH).
Also see *Control Panel > Programs and Features* for Java versions.

Comment: It didn't install anything, and as I said, I uninstalled all versions of jdk that I had, and reinstalled only jdk1.8.0_191, but it didn't work

Comment: I suggest to uninstall the new products and see if this helps. If not uninstall netbeans and java using [Revo Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html), scrub all folders and the registry for netbeans and java, then reinstall your original java and netbeans that worked. If this works, be careful with installing the other products.

Comment: but didn't the log file give any information on what the problem might be, or are you not familiar with how to find the problem in them. Because I really don't want to uninstall the other software unless it will fix the problem for sure.

Comment: I didn't find the logs useful, so had to give a broader advice. You should examine the products you installed with an eye to which one could have conflicted with netbeans or eclipse. To conflict with both of them, java must be somehow broken.

Comment: I uninstalled the software but I still get the same result. It might be important to inform you that after I had this problem I went to check if the environment variables were ok, but noticed that the "path" was not there, so I had to set it again. I don't know what could have deleted because I am positive that I didn't. Could a software be responsible for such a thing?  I am more or less positive that the environment variables are set correctly now.

Comment: One of the products you installed is very buggy or contains malware. If you have uninstalled them (hopefully the shady product did uninstall itself fully), try to reinstall java and the faster to install among netbeans and exclipse to see if any improvement.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely possibility for your NetBeans problem is that it is configured to use an installation of JDK 8 that does not exist. That would certainly explain the failure of NetBeans to even start.

In support of that idea, this is shown in the NetBeans log file:

> Option found: netbeans_jdkhome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121

However, you state that you are running **jdk1.8.0_191** rather than **jdk1.8.0_121**. Assuming that you want to use update 191, you should:

- Uninstall any older versions of JDK 8 if necessary (though it looks like you have already done this).
- Configure NetBeans to use **jdk1.8.0_191** instead of **jdk1.8.0_121**.

To configure NetBeans:

- Locate the text file **netbeans.conf**. It is in the **etc** directory under the installation directory for NetBeans 8.2. Open that file in any text editor.
- Locate the line containing the property **netbeans_jdkhome**.
- If that line is commented out by the use of a leading `#` then delete that `#` symbol.
- Ensure that the property value is set to the path of the installed release of JDK 8 that you want to use. For example, in your case the line should probably look like this:

  **netbeans_jdkhome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191**
- Save the file **netbeans.conf** and start NetBeans. It should work now.
- If NetBeans fails to start update your question with the new content of the NetBeans log file.

FYI, note that NetBeans does not care about the settings in Windows environment variables such as `PATH`. All it cares about are its own configuration settings, such as those in **netbeans.conf**.

The cause of your problem with Eclipse is less obvious, but your `PATH` settings show a lot of Java directories that I don't have. Are they all definitely needed? One thing that is definitely incorrect is that you have `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin;` specified in the `PATH` twice, so correct that. Then retry your Eclipse installation once NetBeans is working.

Comment: Sorry for the late replay. About the the property netbeans_jdkhome, it is actually the right one, I uploaded the old log file by mistake ( the one that I got when I had jdk1.8.0_121). I will replace it with the log that I get now (Even though they are the same, the only difference is the jdk version). I already tried what you mentioned in your comment before but it didn't work. Netbeans still won't start. About the "path" environment variable, it is actually different than what the log is showing, I don't know why is that. My actual "path" is different and has only one path to jdk1.8.0_191.

Comment: @NoussaSmiley OK, understood. For your NetBeans issue, try putting the value of **netbeans_jdkhome** in file **netbeans.conf** in quotes so that the line looks like this: **netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191"**   (I think the space within the file name may be causing problems.)

Comment: It is already like that. It already has quotes, so that is not the problem. It still isn't working.